# Iterate a lua table in c with a custom pair function

Tags: c, lua, iterator

I'd like to use the Ordered Table Simple example, I found at the lua-wiki site. Here's [the link](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OrderedTableSimple).

In Lua it iterates fine with this:

```
for i,v in t:opairs() do
   print( i,v )
end
```

Instead iterating in lua, I want pass `t` to a C method and iterate the table there. In the C API I found only `lua_next` for the original `pairs` iterator. How can I iterate this lua code in C ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is write a custom `next` C function that mimics `lua_next` but works on that ordered table instead having `opairs` method.

```
int luaL_orderednext(luaState *L)
{
  luaL_checkany(L, -1);                 // previous key
  luaL_checktype(L, -2, LUA_TTABLE);    // self
  luaL_checktype(L, -3, LUA_TFUNCTION); // iterator
  lua_pop(L, 1);                        // pop the key since 
                                        // opair doesn't use it

  // iter(self)
  lua_pushvalue(L, -2);
  lua_pushvalue(L, -2);
  lua_call(L, 1, 2);

  if(lua_isnil(L, -2))
  {
    lua_pop(L, 2);
    return 0;
  }
  return 2;
}
```

You can then use it in C similar to `lua_next`:

```
int orderedtraverse(luaState *L)
{
  lua_settop(L, 1);
  luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);

  // t:opairs()
  lua_getfield(L, 1, "opairs");
  lua_pushvalue(L, -2);
  lua_call(L, 1, 2);

  // iter, self (t), nil
  for(lua_pushnil(L); luaL_orderednext(L); lua_pop(L, 1))
  {
    printf("%s - %s\n", 
           lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -2)), 
           lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -1)));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note, I didn't test this but it should work.